# Mergerfs not merging drives in fstab

Tags: mount

I've installed the latest 2.32.4 release of mergerfs and after putting in the following fstab config, the drives won't merge:

```
LABEL=writable  /        ext4   defaults        0 0
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
/dev/sda2 /mnt/drive1 ntfs-3g permissions,auto 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /mnt/drive2 ntfs-3g permissions,auto 0 0

/mnt/drive* /mnt/pidrive/Plex fuse.mergerfs allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs
```

Another note is that the sdb2 drive is mounting in read only mode, but sdb1 is read write. They're both NTFS drives.

Here's lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    47M  1 loop /snap/certbot/1043
loop1         7:1    0  47.6M  1 loop /snap/certbot/1094
loop2         7:2    0  87.8M  1 loop /snap/core/10910
loop3         7:3    0  87.7M  1 loop /snap/core/10956
loop4         7:4    0  48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/1990
loop5         7:5    0  48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/2002
loop6         7:6    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19648
loop7         7:7    0  57.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/974
loop8         7:8    0  61.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19040
loop9         7:9    0  28.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11584
loop10        7:10   0    28M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11408
sda           8:0    0 903.6G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0 903.6G  0 part /mnt/drive1
sdb           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0   128M  0 part
└─sdb2        8:18   0 931.4G  0 part /mnt/drive2
mmcblk0     179:0    0 119.4G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 119.1G  0 part /
```

Comment: If you review the ReadMe at https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs you might not want to use it in a critical or production system.

Comment: Without you providing details on what you mean by "won't merge" there isn't much that can be done to help. NTFS is not POSIX compliant. There are a number of issues you could experience due to that. As for @heynnema's comment I've no idea what that is reference to. mergerfs is perfectly fine to run in production systems.

Comment: @trapexit Sorry, I'm quite new to Linux. So the individual drives are mounting into drive1 and drive2 but if I go into /mnt//pidrive/Plex there are no files. I was expecting the files from drive1 and drive2 to be merged there. I don't know any other information I can give you. Maybe some logs somewhere?